# Hibernate - getHibernateTemplate repeated parameters in query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

```
String query = "SELECT Vehicle, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( Vehicle.lat ) ) * cos( radians( Vehicle.lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( Vehicle.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM VehicleDetails Vehicle";

Object[] params  = {lat,lng};

List<VehicleDetails> vehicledata = getHibernateTemplate().find(query,params);
```

Two params 'lat' and 'lng'. The number '37' in the query is the 'lat' value. This value is repeated twice in the query. Parameters are assign using '?' but in this case the first '?' will be 'lat' and 2nd '?' will be 'lng' and there is another 3rd  number. How do I assign the 'lat' parameter in the query twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply like this :

```
String query = "SELECT Vehicle, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( ? ) ) * cos( radians( ? ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( ? ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM VehicleDetails Vehicle";

Object[] params  = {lat,lng, lat};

List<VehicleDetails> vehicledata = getHibernateTemplate().find(query,params);
```

or Using namedParameters

```
 String query = "SELECT Vehicle, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( :lat ) ) * cos( radians( :lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( :lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM VehicleDetails Vehicle";

 List<VehicleDetails> vehicledata = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(query,{'lat','lng'},{lat, lng});
```

Version with limit :

```
Query q = getHibernateTemplate().getSession().createQuery(query );
q.setFirstResult(0); // modify this to adjust paging
q.setMaxResults(20);

// For named parameters
q.setParamter("lat",lat);
q.setParamter("lng",lng);

// For non named parameters
q.setParamter(0,lat);
q.setParamter(1,lng);
q.setParamter(2,lat);
List<VehicleDetails> vehicledata = q.list();
```

Comment: Vyncent, One reply from you and problem is solve. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Vyncent, How to add LIMIT in the same query. Normal SQL query LIMIT is throwing error.


'String query = "SELECT Vehicle, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( :lat ) ) * cos( radians( :lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( :lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM VehicleDetails Vehicle LIMIT 0 , 20";'

**Error:** org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIMIT